# Input and screen change to output

Tags: javascript, html

so after my earlier question I realized what I can do now. But I have run into a problem. I tried a few ways and google search and nothing worked. I'm trying to have when the user opens up my page they get a screen to input lets say their name and then when they submit it fades away and a new screen appears saying Welcome, "name" and then fades away and the page loads. this is what I got basically just the input and output I guess. if its a lot I understand. thanks. the divs are there for the styling.

EDIT:

This is what ive got so far. I know a little messy.
https://plnkr.co/edit/gOOM3VlokaP7qAUdCVfV?p=preview

-------------------------.----------------------------------------------

```
<div id="name_container">

    <input type="text" id="txtName" value="">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="inputTxt();showMessage()">
</div>
<div id="welcomeMessage">
    <p id="txtOutput"></p>
</div>
<script>
        function inputTxt() {
            var name = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
            document.getElementById("txtOutput").innerHTML = 'Welcome to my AMD Website,  ' + name;
        }



</script>
```

Comment: Something like this? https://plnkr.co/edit/cRNNakgorWUod8b3LWKN?p=preview

Comment: Yes, but i would not like to use the prompt method.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Plunker out: https://plnkr.co/edit/OhLznXwtcqaXvddDmAqT?p=preview

Fade animations are provided by [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). jQuery is being used, although you could write this in javascript too.

Explanation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var name = "";
  $(".first").addClass("animated fadeInDown"); <-- First fade animation happens


  $(".button1").click(function() { <-- If this button is pressed, the value in the input field gets stored to name
    name = $("#name").val();

    $("#welcome").text(name); <-- this adds name to the span field.

    $(this).parent("div").addClass("animated fadeOutUp"); <-- this causes div to disappear

    $(".second").addClass("animated fadeInDown"); <-- this causes the next div to appear
  });

  $(".button2").click(function() { <-- After this, the last div is loaded.



    $(this).parent("div").addClass("animated fadeOutUp");

    $(".third").addClass("animated fadeInDown");
  });

});
```

Comment: Wow is actually what I needed. I need the 2nd screen, the second div to fade out after a few seconds and third class to come in after. I'll try to figure it out i havent messed with jquery that much. i came with another way but it's a little buggy atm.

Comment: You can achieve this with a timer: setTimeout(function(){
  alert("Boom!");
}, 2000). <-- After two seconds, this alert will be called.